# Is array better than objects for storing and searching key value pairs in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am fetching data from db and storing it in an array in key value pair, so that i can get values of respective keys as below

```
var test = [];
for ()            //fetching and storing from db
{
    test[key_array[i]] = "value i";
       .
       .
       .   
}


test["id_1"] = "value 1"; //to get the value of id_<number>
```

we can achive this though objects too. I wanted to know which is the better option to consider, if we want a fast and optimized code

Comment: why do you take an array isntwad of a plain object?

Comment: in java script everything is an object so you can assign it properties like this but initializing it as an array makes no difference

Comment: it makes a difference, because arrays have more methods than pure objects. the main problem is, you can nor persist arrays with stringify with other properties than indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is array better than objects for storing and searching key value pairs in javascript?

No. In fact, you're not using the array as an array, you're using it as an object. You could literally change your

```
var test = [];
```

to

```
var test = {};
// or
var test = Object.create(null); // To avoid it having a prototype
```

and it would do the same thing you're seeing now:

```js
var test = {};
test["id_1"] = "value_1";
console.log(test["id_1"]);

var test2 = Object.create(null);
test2["id_2"] = "value_2";
console.log(test2["id_2"]);
```

(And you should change it, since using an array only for its object features is confusing to people maintaining your code.)

`[]` is a property accessor that accepts the property name as a string. (We use it with standard arrays as well, using numbers, but in theory they get converted to strings before the property is looked up, because standard arrays [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)¹.)

In ES2015+, of course, you'd probably use a `Map`, not an object:

```js
const test = new Map();
test.set("id_1", "value_1");
console.log(test.get("id_1"));
```

---

¹ That's a post on my anemic little blog.

Comment: ..."You could literally change your
`var test = [];`
to
`var test = {};`... In fact you _should_ to avoid confusion

Comment: @scraaappy - Quite so. I'm surprised I didn't say that (originally ;-) ).

Answer (score 0):

Arrays, are just a kind of object specialized for storing sequences of things. If you evaluate typeof [], it produces "object".

https://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html#h_cqg63Sxe3o

The idea of an array is store sequences of data with the same type or logic structure. Thus, is logic put the data come from a db into an array.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you should avoid this because it can become very confusing :

```js
var test = [];
test["id_1"] = "value_1";
test[-1] = "value_0";

console.log(test[-1],test["id_1"]);
console.log(test.length,Array.isArray(test));
```

It lets you think that `test` is an array (and it is) but `test[-1]` and `test["id_1"]` are not part of the array (that's why `Array.isArray(test)` returns `true`, but `test.length` is still equal to 0. See explanation on link provided by mister T.J. Crowder